Picklist Choice Record Type visibility controlled by Tooling API
I'm updating picklist choices by using Tooling API callouts to the User object, pulling in user names based on their Role. This was working great (thanks to some great help from people on here). But then I needed to start to specify the visibility of those new choices to be visible for all Record Types of an object, or they wouldn't appear when creating the record.
I've added code which queries the object, collects a list of all RecordTypeIDs, and trying to use that to set the visibility to all record types.
global class PicklistValuesUpdatePlayer implements Schedulable {
    
    global void execute(SchedulableContext ctx) {
    
        updatePicklistValues();
    }
@future(callout=true)
    public static void updatePicklistValues() {
        Date yesterday = System.today().addDays(-1);
        // Query for deactivated users
        List<User> deactivatedUsers = [
            SELECT LastName, FirstName
            FROM User
            WHERE IsActive = false AND LastModifiedDate >= :yesterday AND LastModifiedDate < :System.today()
        ];

        // Query for newly activated ‘Player’ users
        List<User> newPlayers = [
            SELECT LastName, FirstName
            FROM User
            WHERE IsActive = true AND UserRole.Name = 'Player' //AND CreatedDate >= :yesterday AND CreatedDate < :System.today()
        ];

        updatePicklistField(deactivatedUsers, newPlayers);
    }
//Modified to include all RecordTypes    
private static void updatePicklistField(List<User> deactivatedUsers, List<User> newPlayers) {
    // Retrieve all Task record types
    List<RecordType> recordTypes = [
        SELECT Id
        FROM RecordType
        WHERE SObjectType = 'Task'
    ];
   
    // Prepare the record types list for the payload
    List<Map<String, Object>> recordTypesPayload = new List<Map<String, Object>>();
    for (RecordType rt : recordTypes) {
        recordTypesPayload.add(new Map<String, Object>{
            'recordTypeId' => rt.Id,
            'visible' => true
        });
    }

    // Setup HTTP request to Tooling API
    HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
    req.setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + UserInfo.getSessionId());
    req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    req.setEndpoint(URL.getOrgDomainURL().toExternalForm() + '/services/data/v60.0/tooling/sobjects/CustomField/00N8L000000vB1x');        
    req.setMethod('PATCH');

    // Construct the metadata changes for deactivation and addition
    List<Map<String, Object>> picklistValues = new List<Map<String, Object>>();
   
    for (User u : deactivatedUsers) {
        picklistValues.add(new Map<String, Object>{
            'isActive' => false,
            'valueName' => u.LastName + ', ' + u.FirstName,
            'recordTypes' => recordTypesPayload
        });
    }

    for (User u : newPlayers) {
        picklistValues.add(new Map<String, Object>{
            'isActive' => true,
            'valueName' => u.LastName + ', ' + u.FirstName,
            'default' => false,
            'recordTypes' => recordTypesPayload
        });
    }

        //picklist metadata

        Map<String, Object> value = new Map<String, Object>{
            'value' => picklistValues
                };
        Map<String, Object> valueSetDefinition = new Map<String, Object>{
            'valueSetDefinition' => value
            };
        Map<String, Object> valueSettings = new Map<String, Object>{
            'valueSettings' => '[]'
            };
                
        //label...
        Map<String, Object> valueSet = new Map<String, Object>{
            'label' => 'Include Business or Commercial Banker',
            'type' => 'Picklist',
            'valueSet' => valueSetDefinition
            };
                
        //FullName...
        Map<String, Object> fieldMetadata = new Map<String, Object>{
            'Metadata' => valueSet,
            'FullName' => 'Activity.Player__c'
            };

        req.setBody(JSON.serialize(fieldMetadata));
       
        Http http = new Http();
        HttpResponse res = http.send(req);
       
        if (res.getStatusCode() != 200) {
            System.debug('Error from Tooling API: ' + res.getBody());
            System.debug('Field Metadata:  ' + JSON.serialize(fieldMetadata));
        }
    }
}

But I'm not sure if this is a legit method of where/how to set the visibility for a choice in the metadata. I don't see the RecordType mentioned anywhere in this Picklist Choice metadata. So I'm guessing I can't do it in the same callout while creating it ?
Create Picklist Metadata
I saw this other question on adding picklist choices to Record Types. But I was hoping to accomplish it by setting them while creating the picklist choice.
As it is now, I'm getting a "Cannot deserialize instance of complexvalue from START_ARRAY value...JSON_PARSER_ERROR".
And this is what my metadata looks like :
Metadata:  {"FullName":"Activity.Manager__c","Metadata":{"valueSet":{"valueSetDefinition":{"value":[{"recordTypes":[{"visible":true,"recordTypeId":"01231000001Aj9hAAC"},{"visible":true,"recordTypeId":"0123q000000tdlfAAA"}],"default":false,"valueName":"Smith, Brian","isActive":true}

I would love it if I could just include that in my callout creating all of the choices and take care of it all just like that. Do you know of any way to make that fly ?
